# Why does Remove-ADGroupMember default to requiring confirmation?

Tags: active-directory, powershell

In a script, I need to manage the membership of a group. Unfortunately, the cmdlet for removing a member from a group, `Remove-ADGroupMember` is always asking for confirmation. This is contradictory to the described behavior of the cmdlet, as there is a `-Confirm` option that is supposed to turn on confirmation. This requires using obscure and poorly documented colon binding of a value to a switch parameter: `-Confirm:$false`, when it would make much more sense to instead use a straightforward `-Force` switch.

Is there a setting in the environment that is changing how the cmdlet behaves? Is this just a poorly implemented feature? Am I missing some obvious documentation that would explain the confusing behavior of switch parameters?

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking why not including "-Confirm" prompts you for confirmation?  By default, without specifying $false the cmdlet will always prompt for confirmation.  The option is there to give you the ability to suppress the confirmation.  It may be confusing in that it is called -Confirm but that is because with PS you specify a value for that parameter.  So you are in essence saying "set -Confirm to false/no".  It would be much more confusing if the parameter were called -NoConfirm and you had to set a value for that parameter!

This is by design.  The default is to prompt when you run this cmdlet without the 
`-Confirm:$false` to be sure that you wanted to run the command.

Some links for knowledge (note they don't answer the question directly, just give you some insight into PS grammar/syntax):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/05/10/594535.aspx

http://www.manning.com/payette/AppCexcerpt.pdf

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj554301.aspx

EDIT: maybe I misinterpreted your question.  I was basing my answer on "there is a -Confirm option that is supposed to turn on confirmation".  If your question is why do I have to use a colon then @DavidV's answer is right on the money.

Comment: Both answers are relevant. I am asking why the AD cmdlet requires an obscure (passing values to switch arguments is obscure) syntax to work normally. Was it deliberate? Is there a reason they chose not to have a -NoConfirm? I am just annoyed and frustrated wasting a few hours hunting down an answer to a problem that shouldn't have been an issue in the beginning. Why bother with a -Switch parameter that cannot even be used as a straight switch parameter?

Comment: The "why" can really only be addressed by the PS Team at MS.  But (IMO) the reasoning is that you typically don't have a parameter that defaults to a negative result in PS.  So having a -NoConfirm switch would still need a value (-NoConfirm:$True) which would be odd syntax here since the default/understood command here asks for confirmation.  So with proper PS syntax by stating "-Confirm:$False" you are saying "change the Confirm parameter to false in this instance".  I've modded my answer to include a few links to check out.

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys I think you mean why didn't they include a `-Force` switch to suppress confirmation, as this `-Confirm` and it's behavior aren't unique to the AD Module.

Comment: Thank you MDMoore, that is an excellent re-phrasing of my question, and quite accurate.

Comment: I should also note @TheCleaner that a `-Switch` that does nothing (when present it has the same behavior as when absent) is far more confusing than a switch with a negative name such as `-NoConfirm`.

Answer (score 3):

A great answer is provided over at Stackoverflow (all credit to manojlds):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525572/powershell-colon-in-commandlet-parameters

Comment: This does explain how to pass a value to a switch parameter. It does not explain the reasoning for a command to include a switch parameter that **does nothing** unless you use an unusual syntax that is never used except in this odd case of a bad default setting.

Comment: 'It is in scenarios where the value for a switch variable itself has to be determined from another variable that the : is used.'  So when using -Confirm $false, $false as a value is not being passed to the switch it's just seen as a separate argument.  Whereas if you use -Confirm:$false you are telling the switch to use the value of '$false'.

Comment: I'm aware of how to pass a parameter to a switch... but the question is why are they using a switch parameter in the first place? Switch parameters are **meant** to be absent (off) or present (on). That is their function, and because of that the `:$parameter` syntax is (rightfully) rarely used and poorly documented.